# Cluster similar words using word2vec

Tags: nlp, data-science, word2vec

I have various restaurant labels with me and i have some words that are unrelated to restaurants as well. like below:

`vegan
vegetarian
pizza
burger
transportation
coffee
Bookstores
Oil and Lube`

I have such mix of around 500 labels. I want to know is there a way pick the similar labels that are related to food choices and leave out words like oil and lube, transportation.

I tried using word2vec but, some of them have more than one word and could not figure out a right way.

Brute-force approach is to tag them manually. But, i want to know is there a way using NLP or Word2Vec to cluster all related labels together.

Comment: For multi-word labels, how about if you take the word2vec vector for each word in the label and average them out and then pass to clustering model?

Comment: What is your data like ? I mean, you used word2vec on what kind of data, exactly?

Comment: @CatalinaChircu i have tried similarity with words restaurant/cuisine/food against different words that i have. My idea is, if there is a way to find all closely similar words, i can pull them out

Comment: OK. I provided an detailed answer. I hope it will help! I worked on word2vec and if the training data is cleaned accordingly and the settings are appropriate, it gives good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word2Vec could help with this, but key factors to consider are:

- How are your word-vectors trained? Using off-the-shelf vectors (like say the popular `GoogleNews` vectors trained on a large corpus of news stories) are unlikely to closely match the senses of these words in your domain, or include multi-word tokens like 'oil_and_lube'. But, if you have a good training corpus from your own domain, with multi-word tokens from a controlled vocabulary (like `oil_and_lube`) that are used in context, you might get quite good vectors for exactly the tokens you need.
- The similarity of word-vectors isn't strictly 'synonymity' but often other forms of close-relation including oppositeness and other ways words can be interchangeable or be used in similar contexts. So whether or not the word-vector similarity-values provide a good threshold cutoff for your particular desired "related to food" test is something you'd have to try out & tinker around. (For example: whether words that are drop-in replacements for each other are closest to each other, or words that are common-in-the-same-topics are closest to each other, can be influenced by whether the `window` parameter is smaller or larger. So you could find tuning Word2Vec training parameters improve the resulting vectors for your specific needs.)

Making more recommendations for how to proceed would require more details on the training data you have available – where do these labels come from? what's the format they're in? how much do you have? – and your ultimate goals – why is it important to distinguish between restaurant- and non-restaurant- labels?

Answer (score 0):

OK, thank you for the details.

In order to train on word2vec  you should take into account the following facts :

1. You need a ***huge*** and ***variate*** text dataset. Review your training set and make sure it contains the useful data you need in order to obtain what you want.
2. Set one sentence/phrase per line.
3. For preprocessing, you need to ***delete punctuation*** and set all strings ***to lower case***.
4. Do **NOT** lemmatize or stemmatize, because the text will be less complex!
5. Try different settings:

   5.1 **Algorithm**: I used word2vec and I can say ***BagOfWords*** (**BOW**) provided better results, on different training sets, than ***SkipGram***.

   5.2 **Number of layers**: 200 layers provide good result

   5.3 **Vector size**: Vector length = 300 is OK.

Now run the training algorithm. The, use the obtained model in order to perform different tasks. For example, in your case, for synonymy, you can compare two words (i.e. vectors) with **cosine** (or **similarity**). From my experience, cosine provides a satisfactory result: the distance between two words is given by a double between 0 and 1. Synonyms have high cosine values, you must find the limit between words which are synonyms and others that are not.